# How to partition 10 billion row SQL tables quickly using AWS?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, database-partitioning

I have a SQL database of data delivered in a normalized format with several tables that have several billions of rows of data. I have decided to partition the large tables into separate tables by itemId since when I query the data I only care about 1 item at a time. I would end up having 5000+ tables at the end after partitioning the data.  The problem is, partitioning the data takes about 25 minutes to build a single table for 1 item.

```
5000 items x 25 minutes = 86.8 days
```

It would take over 86 days to fully partition my entire SQL database. My entire database is about 2.5TB.

Is this something I can leverage AWS for to parallelize on an item level? Can I use AWS database migration services to host the database in its current form and then use AWS process to churn through all of the 5000 queries to partition the big tables into 5000 smaller tables with 2M rows each?

If not, is this something I just have to throw more hardware at to make it run faster (CPU or RAM)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use a simple RDS (with, admittedly, a reasonable machine) does a proper index not work on the entire dataset?  This sounds a bit like an [XY Problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) in that you've come up with a solution and not a problem.

Comment: Please specify what you mean. what is your "SQL database" is that redshift?(redshift doesn't do partitioning internally) if you are using redshift spectrum/athena then you can post your data into s3 buckets but these can generally be quite large. The main thing to flesh out is what you are you attempting? what is the use case? where is the data now and what problems are you trying to overcome?

Comment: The current SQL database is SQL Server 2016. The use case is that pulling the data for one item from this table takes a long time so I am trying to partition the very large table into many tables by item since I always just want one item at a time.  When I say long time, I mean several minutes for a query, but if i want to pull this data to build a full history of the item (manipulate the data) it could take weeks. If I partition it by item the query is reduced to milliseconds instead of minutes.  But partitioning still takes a long time.

Comment: To be more specific I am looking at financial data on a stock level. I have a huge table of values which represent characteristics of companies.  I have about 40K companies and approximately 5000 characteristics. Also this database is highly normalized so the actual company names and dates are in other tables. I only want to look at one characteristic at a time so partitioning the large table into separate tables by characteristics yields 5000 tables, which each holding historical data for all the companies for that particular characteristic.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't seem like a good strategy.  For one thing, simple arithmetic is that 10,000,000,000 rows with 5,000 rows per item results in 2,000,000 partitions in the table.

The limit in Redshift (by default) is [1,000,000 partition per table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/amazon-redshift-limits.html):

> Amazon Redshift Spectrum has the following quotas when using the
>   Athena or AWS Glue data catalog:
>
> - A maximum of 10,000 databases per account.
> - A maximum of 100,000 tables per database.
> - A maximum of 1,000,000 partitions per table.
> - A maximum of 10,000,000 partitions per account.

You should re-think your partitioning strategy.  Or perhaps your problem is not suitable for Redshift.  There may be other database strategies more suitable for your use-case.  (This is not the forum for recommending specific software solutions, however.)

Comment: To clarify, it would be 5000 partitions, with 2,000,000 rows per partition.

Comment: @quantcoder . . . Your sample estimate refers to 5,000 rows, which is where that estimate comes from.

Comment: sorry i mean 5000 itemID's not rows.  A single itemID can refer to serveral millions of rows in this one table.  To be specific I'm dealing with financial data on companies where 5000 represents the number of characteristics i have in my database. I have historical data on over 40,000 companies for 20+ years. When I query the database for a single characteristic for a single point in time across all companies, that takes a long time.  If i break the large table by characteristic, my queries improve dramatically.  However partitioning the table by characteristic still takes 25 minutes each.

Comment: @quantcoder . . . Time is also commonly used for partitioning.  But what you say makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Use the itemid as `sortkey` and `distkey`. if the table is `vacumm`ed properly and you select one itemid this should have good results, where access time is almost as good as a single table. `distkey` is used to distribute the data between shards, which means each itemid's blocks would be stored together on the same shard making retrieving all of them faster. Having the itemid also be `sortkey` means that for itemid's with small row numbers that all exist on the same shard, finding the rows within the table's blocks on a shard would be as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a separate table for each item, where every other attribute of the table remains the same, doesn't seem logical. If the data format is the same, then keep the data in the same table unless there is a particular problem to overcome.

If you set the `itemId` as the `SORTKEY` on a Redshift table, then Redshift will be able to skip-over the blocks that do not contain a desired value (when using `WHERE itemId = 'xxx'`). This will be highly efficient.

Admittedly, trying to keep such a large table sorted would probably be too hard to `VACUUM`. It would still work reasonably well without the `SORTKEY` since blocks can still be skipped, but not as efficiently because the data for that `itemId` would be spread over more blocks.

Comment: the particular problem i'm trying to overcome is the amount of time it takes to pull several rows attributed to one itemID.